# PHP echo enum type from database

Tags: php, database, enums, echo

I am currently developing a website where the user fills out a form to upload an item they wish to sell.

The code for this section of the form looks like this :

```
    <?php
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $cat = $row["category"];

    }
    ?>
 <div class="col m6">
  <label for="Input">Item Catagory</label>
  <select class="_width100" id="Input">
    <option value="Option 1"> </option>
    <option value="Option 2"> </option>
    <option value="Option 3"> </option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

I wish to echo each of the enum options within my php database (see image below) as options for the user to pick from within the form. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

[Database table row name: Category type: Enum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJvrh.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like do something like that:

```
<div class="col m6">
    <label for="Input">Item Catagory</label>
    <select class="_width100" id="Input" name="some_name">
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
            <?php
                $cat = $row["category"];
                $id = $row["id"];
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $id ?>"><?= $cat ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your table structure. All the values, which are stored in the ENUM datatype should be stored in a single database table. Let us call this table *categories*. This table hast two columns. An auto increment column as the id and the value itself, which should be a unique column, so that every category is stored only one time. Actually your already existing column category should be an integer column as foreign key to the other data table 's id column. This structure is a so called 1:n relationship. One category could be used for n entries in another table.

The next advantage is, that you can list all unique items from the category table. ;)